Compact register map with TikZ
This is part of the problem, described in Tikz for CPU operation drawing/schematic
The aim here is to create a register name with bit fields with Tikz. I followed Draw register map with TikZ and shortened and renamed it for my purposes.
What I would like to have is:

and have so far:
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{chains, scopes}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\bitrect}[2]{
    \draw [thick] (0,0) rectangle (#1,1);
    % draw ticks for bit labels
    \pgfmathsetmacro\bitwidth{#1-1}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\bitwidth}
      \draw (\x,1) -- (\x, 0.8);
  \bitlabels{#1}{#2}
}
\newcommand{\psw}[3]{
  \draw (#1,0) rectangle ++(#2,1) node[pos=0.5]{#3};
}
\newcommand{\pswX}[3]{
 \draw [thick, fill=red!20] (#1,0) rectangle ++(#2,1) node[pos=0.5]{#3};
}
\newcommand{\bitlabels}[2]{
  \foreach \bit in {1,...,#1}{
     \pgfmathsetmacro\bitnumber{#2}
     \node [above] at (\bit-0.5, 1) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\bitnumber}};
   }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=B going right]
  \node[draw, on chain=B, fill=yellow!30] (PSW){APSW}; % This displaces the names N, Z, ...
  \begin{scope}[xshift=7mm, on chain=B]
    \bitrect{32}{32-\bit} % {length}{index label expression}
    \psw{0}{1}{N}    % {start bit}{length}{label}
    \psw{1}{1}{Z}
    \pswX{2}{1}{C}
    \psw{3}{1}{V}
    \psw{4}{1}{Q}
    \psw{4}{5}{XX}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

which shows

For the bits I am interested in representing, the representation of only the left part is sufficient. I would like to abbreviate the lower bits as in my drawing (but implicitly keep the 32 bits as flags). I also like to have the width of each of the bits in the bitbox thinner (also to shorten the width of the whole picture). Simple scaling each of the bitboxes by 70% (multiplying by 0.7 inside the source) renders the source to not readable anymore (not shown here).
Putting the register name "SW" into the figure on the left side moves the Bit names N, Z, C, ... to the right for a small amount (not centered inside the boxes anymore) - the bit identifiers within the bit box must be centered. Why does this happen?
To the left of the bit box is the name of this register, and it should be 1pt next to it at the same height (it represents exactly this register content), so the bit box should have exactly the same height. The height shall be equal to the size of the register name "SW". This size in my source isn't intended.

The framework you use draws everything completely, you would have to delete some things, the option here is to nest the drawing of each node but maintaining control of what goes and where, then draw the specific characteristics using the points of the nodes that are generated when assigning them a name.
RESULT:

MWE:
\documentclass[border=2pt,tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        font=\sffamily,
        N/.style={
            draw,
            fill=green!20,
            inner sep=4pt,
            minimum height=1.5em
            }
    ]
    %Start Drawing the thing.
    \node[N]at (0,0)(R0){SW};
    \foreach \r/\d/\b/\c [count=\t from 0] in {
        1/N/31/none,
        2/Z/30/none,
        3/C/29/red!20,
        4/V/28/none,
        5/Q/27/none,
        6/\,/26/none,
        7/XX/25/none,
        8/\,/24/none,
        9/\,/\,/none,
        10/\,/\,/none,
        11/\,/1/none,
        12/\,/0/none%
        }{
        \node[
            right=0 of R\t,
            label=90:\tiny \b,
            minimum height=1.5em,
            minimum width=1em,
            inner sep=2,
            fill=\c
        ](R\r){\d};
    }
    \foreach \k in {1,...,12}{\draw(R\k.north east) -- ++(0,-0.25em);}
    \draw(R1.north west) rectangle (R5.south east);
    \draw(R6.north west) rectangle (R8.south east);
    \draw(R8.north east) -- (R10.100) to [out=-135, in=45] (R10.-100) -| cycle;
    \draw(R12.north east) -- (R10.80) to [out=-135, in=45] (R10.-80) -| cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Really elegant! I'd add a bit of padding (small phantom box) between the name box and the first bit box.

Thank you, obviously \phantom[2pt} has no effect inside Tikz figure, but \hspace{2pt} works as expected.

Yes, elegant. I've learned a lot! Why does the node R0 looks like to have a smaller border than the bit box? I can cover this by drawing this thick, but I wouldn't expect this.

@olStckEx about the padding --- I meant adding outer xsep=2pt to the keys of the R0 box. The difference in size is that the external anchors (north west etc...) that are used for drawing the boxes around the not-drawn boxes are padded by "outer sep" normally. Try using outer sep=0pt and see what happens.  See https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf./pgf/outer:sep
